# VBA Excel - Transform Column value To another Column along with inserting blank row

Tags: vba, excel

I want to tranform the values.

Suppose in `A1:A20` there are 20 values and in `B1:B20` also 20 values.

I want to copy values of column B in such manner that outcome should be:

Cell `A1` value is `A1`, cell `A2` value is `B1`, cell `A3` value is `A2`, cell A4 value is `B1`.

Likewise in cell `A40` value is `B20`. 
(for more clarity i have attached image)

So here first step is inserting blanck cells alternatively in column A
and than copy value of column B in that blank cells.

For more clarity Please find the image

[image: example].

Comment: Sounds good. Why don't you have a shot at it, then come back to use with any specific problem you're having with your attempt, and we'll be happy to help then.

Comment: good idea.. but here some techie solved my problem without asking any history. 3 cheers for them!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always post what you have tried first !

```
Sub test()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To 20 Step 2
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Insert
    Next i

    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:B40").copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, SkipBlanks:=True

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried it and its working fine. Column B cells have bkgrnd color green. so is it possible that bolumn B's properties (lyk bkgrnd color, font color..) also get copied?

Comment: I have updated the code , basically you need to use xlPasteAll to to paste everything unlike the initial code which was only pasting values.

Comment: @Downvoter - Please leave a comment as it would help me to shape my answers properly.

Comment: Hi Imran .. even with your first code..my problem get resolved.. i got idea what to do with my VBA... final result required 3 VBA modules.. and for what u help out is the main concern.. thnx a lot again.

Comment: why someone has vote down to this answer.. this one is the perfect one... Thanks Imran once again - from GK

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not exactly what you are looking for but an alternative solution is to use a regular formula like below.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$B$9,ROUNDDOWN(ROW()/2,0),ISODD(ROW())+1),"")
```

[image]

But this won't give the color you are looking for.  Just throw out an alternative method for your reference.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. but i want to use cell's value as it is.. means require font color, cell bkgrnd color also. it's client requirement.

Comment: Figured and so this is just for your reference.  VBA is the only way here for you to achieve your goal.